# Determine whether 2 dates ranges overlap excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have beginning date and an end date of a contract. Let's say 01/01/2017 and 01/01/2018 respectively.

I have a date that the contract has been cancelled. Let's say 01/07/2017.

When the contract is cancelled I need to assign the premium paid for the contract back to the client.

And I have a period in which if the contract goes into at any point then the amount returned is different (0.5 times). Let's say June to November.

So there is a 1 month overlap. Therefore the premium I return will be 0.5*return amount.

I can't figure out how to put this into an excel formula. I just need to say are the months of June - November contained in a period. In the case above 01/01/2017 - 01/01/2018.

Comment: Can you specify, are you using MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: yup dd/mm/yyyy thanks

Comment: Are you trying to figure out if July 1 is in the June to November period, or if the June to November period is contained in the January 2017 to January 2018 period?

Comment: the period of the contract is from 1 Jan 2017 - 1 Jan 2018. If they cancel it and any day of the running period 1 Jan 2017 - date of cancel is in june through to november then I need to flag it. So a simple yes will do. If no days in the period 1 Jan 2017 - date of cancel go into any date between june and november then it would say no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1**

I think you should be able to just look and see if the end of the Usage Period is inside the Half Refund Period. If so, you can simply use

```
=AND({UsageEnd}>={HalfRefundBegin},{UsageEnd}<={HalfRefundEnd})
```

[image]

**Answer 2**

If you *really* want to know if one date range overlaps another, there are three possible situations:

- The start of Period 2 is during Period 1
- The end of Period 2 is during Period 1
- The start of Period 2 is before Period 1, and the end of Period 2 is after Period 1

In this situation you can use

```
=OR(                                                 // any of these three options:
    AND({P2Begin}>={P1Begin},{P2Begin}<={P1End}),    // start of Period 2 during Period 1
    AND({P2End}>={P1Begin},{P2End}<={P1End}),        // end of Period 2 during Period 1
    AND({P2Begin}<{P1Begin},{P2End}>{P1End}))        // start P2 before P1, end P2 after P1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go